# How to show the graph with high data in a given space?

Tags: ios, core-plot, linegraph

I am using Line Graph of Core Plot in my project. The thing is when I kept the data of my X-axis and Y-axis like: 1,2,3....10, everything worked fine. But now the data is like: X-axis: 0, 150, 500.... and on Y-axis: 0,1000,2000 and so on.

So now my graph is not fully visible in the given area. I know it is because the range on my Y-axis is getting too high and it is not visible. Some code that might possibly the reason for it:

```
// Setup scatter plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

plotSpace.xRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(8)];
plotSpace.yRange                = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(5)];

// Restrict y range to a global range
CPTPlotRange *globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-2.5)
                                                          length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(5.0)];
plotSpace.globalYRange = globalYRange;

CPTPlotRange *globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-0.2)
                                                          length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(17.0)];

plotSpace.globalXRange=globalXRange;
```

[image: This graph is when my data range is getting too high]

Answer (score 1):

The `xRange` and `yRange` are too small to display all of the plot data.

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(500)]; 
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(2000)];
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

No luck :( It becomes as per its shown above. I dont want to compress the data. The distance between the months should be as same as the figure posted in the question. The Y axis data is still not getting visible completely. My global X and Y range is like this

> CPTPlotRange *globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange
>   plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-2.5)
>                                                                 length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(5.0)];
>       plotSpace.globalYRange = globalYRange;
>
> ```
> CPTPlotRange *globalXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-0.2)
>                                                           length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(17.0)];
>
> plotSpace.globalXRange=globalXRange;
> ```

Comment: This contribution to the page seems to be an addendum and not an answer. The OP seems not to have visited for a year, and so I think this can safely be deleted - voting as NAA.